# how to differentiate row echelon matrix from reduced row echelon.

Tags: matrices

what the difference between row echelon matrix and reduced row echelon?

Answer (score 0):

In RREF the only entry in a pivot column is a leading 1 whereas in REF there can be multiple entries in a pivot column. The way I was tough the leading coefficient does not need to be 1 in REF but some books say it should be 1 even in REF. For Example:

[RREF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhX93.png)
[REF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pjrh.png)